# Confusion regarding Handling of Different Pointers by Compiler

Tags: pointers, compiler-construction, compiler-theory

I have a couple of confusions regarding pointers.

I am putting all of them in the form of question.

1) **How does compiler handle various pointers?**

2) **How does a compiler figure out the data type of pointers passed at compile time?**

All I know, pointers are stored in the memory in the form of an Unsigned Integer which is used to hold the base address of the object that it is pointing.
Now, is it the *Symbol Table* that plays the key role?

Comment: What tells you compiler determines data type of pointers at runtime?

Comment: The question is a little confused, but it shows curiosity about the right things.  To help you to focus the question, consider that the compiler, by definition, does not figure anything out at runtime, but only at compile-time.  In a compiled C program, it is normally impossible to figure out the type of an object pointed to at run-time; rather, the type must be known at compile-time.  In C++, there is dynamic type identification, but from the tenor of your question I doubt that that is what you want.

Comment: @thb, Well, actually what I thought that at Compile time during Symbol Table formation at **Lexical Analysis** phase, compiler figures out pointers and writes out adequate information regarding the type of pointer. And I wanted to know about the correctness of this.

Comment: Be careful about assuming that pointers are "really" unsigned integers.  They're typically represented similarly, but it's better to think of pointers ad *pointers*.  For example, there are systems where pointers are represented internally as a base and an offset, and two different base+offset pairs can point to the same memory location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a concrete example would help.  Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const double step_size = 5.0; // degrees of arc

struct Location {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
};

void go_north(struct Location *const loc) {
    loc->latitude += step_size;
}

int main() {
    struct Location there;
    there.latitude  =   41.0;
    there.longitude = -101.5;
    go_north(&there);
    printf("Lat. %6.1f, long. %6.1f.\n", there.latitude, there.longitude);
    return 0;
}
```

How does the compiler know that the address *go_north()* receives is the address of a *struct Location?*  Answer:  the programmer has said so, by writing the function control *void go_north(struct Location *const loc).*

Regarding your comment on lexical analysis, believe it or not, the linker does not need to know anything about the size or layout of an object pointed to, even if pointers to such objects are passed around between various **.o* objects.  This is why header files are used:  so that the pre-link compiler proper knows the layout at pre-linking compile time.  A lot of strange things can go in a symbol table in special circumstances, so I'll not be so bold as to assert, categorically, that no symbol table ever contains the information you suggest; but in normal usage the symbol table omits the information, because the linker does not need it.

One suspects that this does not altogether answer your question, but the example might help to focus the question to make it specific enough that it can be answered.  So, if a concrete example helps, plus this partial answer, here they are.

(If you happen to be on a Linux platform, you might find the *readelf* command very interesting.)

Comment: I am actually unable to figure out what you meant by "no symbol table ever contains the information you suggest" .. If those variables are not stored, then how come semantic analysis be possible? Did you mean to say that they are not stored as pointer but as normal variable? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You and I were using the term *symbol table* differently.  Yes, you are right.  Internally within the compiler, at compile time, there temporarily exists a table that contains the information you seek.  However, not all the information in this table is exported to the linker.  For instance, in the example, no information about the automatic variable *there* is exported to the linker (except maybe as a debugging symbol, if you have instructed the compiler to emit such).

Comment: now that my query is little bit clear to you, can you please tell me how are the pointers treated in that temporary table(symbol table which is created at lexical analysis phase of a compiler)? Are they treated as normal variables? If so and if i understood correctly, for your example, datatype of _loc_ (which is _struct location_) will be stored in symbol table; but it is not necessarily passed to linker. After lexical, syntax, semantic analysis and code optimization, it will merely hold address of some other location in the memory. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sarthak:  I know very little about optimization, so let me refrain from comment on that point; but, otherwise, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

1) How does compiler handle various pointers?

They are handled as memory addresses. Usually 16 or 32 or 64 bit unsigned integer.

2) How does a compiler figure out the data type of pointers passed at runtime?

The C-compiler doesn't figure out any data types at the runtime. Pointer types are figured out at the compile time. At runtime the pointers are just stupid memory addresses pointing to unknown types.

Answer (score -1):

There is no feature built into the C language for figuring out the type of a pointer at run time.  You always know the type at compile time.

```
void(char * x)
{
  // x points to a char
}
```

Comment: Ok. But if I consider in general, not being language specific?

Comment: @sarthak: You cannot be language agonist when you ask a language specific q.

Comment: @Als, it's not about being language agonist, I wanted to know the process that compiler takes care about when it encounters a pointer.

Comment: @sarthak I suggest you inspect the assembly output of your compiler to get some intuition about what how pointers are used and try to ask a more specific question next time.